Best cluster scope IPAM using bridge CNI?
What's the best cluster scope IPAM using bridge CNI? host local IPAM assign a block of address to each node, which is not ideal for managing cluster as a whole. Please include the network layout and CNI config in the answer.

If you want to assign IP addresses to the pods across all the nodes in a cluster, you can use Whereabouts is the best choice. Compared to other IPAM plugins like host-local, it was assigned the IP addresses to pods on the same node. Whereabouts it assigns IP addresses as cluster-wide. It is used for both IPv4 & IPv6 addressing.
Network Layout: If you take an address range, like 192.168.2.0/24 in CIDR notation, and will assign IP addresses within that range. For this case, it will assign IP addresses from 192.168.2.1 to 192.168.2.255 and Pods will be assigned IP addresses within the cluster network range. Each node in the cluster will have pods connected to a virtual bridge created by bridge CNI.
Network Layout Whereabouts plugin :

IPAM Configuration using whereabouts:
apiVersion: cni.helm.sh/v1
kind: Network
metadata:
  name: whereabouts-network-example
spec:
  cni:
    type: whereabout
    whereabout:
      cidr: "192.168.0.0/24"
      ipam:
        type: whereabout
        whereabout:
          cidr: "192.168.0.0/24"

and if you want a bridge between the nodes, For creating bridge configurations.
Bridge CNI Configuration:
apiVersion: cni.helm.sh/v1
kind: Network
metadata:
  name: bridge-network-sample
spec:
  cni:
    type: bridge
    bridge:
      name: bridge-name
      ipam:
        type: whereabout
        whereabout:
          cidr: "192.168.0.0/24"

Also refer to this whereabouts plugin and Fatih nar’s medium blog for more information.

If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information.
